# Working with Starling and multiple instances of Mongrel through Mongrel Cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, starling-server

Situation:

- In a typical cluster setup, I have a 5 instances of mongrel running behind Apache 2.
- In one of my initializer files, I schedule a cron task using `Rufus::Scheduler` which basically sends out a couple of emails.

Problem:

- The task runs 5 times, once for each mongrel instance and each recipient ends up getting 5 mails (despite the fact I store logs of each sent mail and check the log before sending). Is it possible that since all 5 instances run the task at exact same time, they end up reading the email logs *before* they are written?

I am looking for a solution that will make the tasks run only once. I also have a Starling daemon up and running which can be utilized.

Answer (score 3):

The [rooster](http://github.com/findchris/rooster/tree/master) rails plugin specifically addresses your issue.  It uses rufus-scheduler and ensures the environment is loaded only once.

Comment: Looks interesting, +1 from me. I am right now using an empty file as a Mutex object, and use it in exclusive lock mode to avoid multiple loading.

Answer (score 1):

The way I am doing it right now:

1. Try to open a file in exclusive locked mode
2. When lock is acquired, check for messages in Starling
3. If message exists, other process has already scheduled the job
4. Set the message again to the queue and exit.
5. If message is not found, schedule the job, set the message and exit

Here is the code that does it:

```
    starling = MemCache.new("#{Settings[:starling][:host]}:#{Settings[:starling][:port]}")
    mutex_filename = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/file.lock"
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new


    # The filelock method, taken from Ruby Cookbook
    # This will ensure unblocking of the files
    def flock(file, mode)
      success = file.flock(mode)
      if success
        begin
          yield file
        ensure
          file.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
        end
      end
      return success
    end

    # open_lock method, taken from Ruby Cookbook
    # This will create and hold the locks
    def open_lock(filename, openmode = "r", lockmode = nil)
      if openmode == 'r' || openmode == 'rb'
        lockmode ||= File::LOCK_SH
      else
        lockmode ||= File::LOCK_EX
      end
      value = nil
      # Kernerl's open method, gives IO Object, in our case, a file
      open(filename, openmode) do |f|
        flock(f, lockmode) do
          begin
            value = yield f
          ensure
            f.flock(File::LOCK_UN) # Comment this line out on Windows.
          end
        end
        return value
      end
    end

    # The actual scheduler
    open_lock(mutex_filename, 'r+') do |f|
      puts f.read
      digest_schedule_message = starling.get("digest_scheduler")
      if digest_schedule_message
        puts "Found digest message in Starling. Releasing lock. '#{Time.now}'"
        puts "Message: #{digest_schedule_message.inspect}"
        # Read the message and set it back, so that other processes can read it too
        starling.set "digest_scheduler", digest_schedule_message
      else
        # Schedule job
        puts "Scheduling digest emails now. '#{Time.now}'"
        scheduler.cron("0 9 * * *") do
          puts "Begin sending digests..."
          WeeklyDigest.new.send_digest!
          puts "Done sending digests."
        end
        # Add message in queue
        puts "Done Scheduling. Sending the message to Starling. '#{Time.now}'"
        starling.set "digest_scheduler", :date => Date.today
      end
    end

    # Sleep will ensure all instances have gone thorugh their wait-acquire lock-schedule(or not) cycle
    # This will ensure that on next reboot, starling won't have any stale messages
    puts "Waiting to clear digest messages from Starling."
    sleep(20)
    puts "All digest messages cleared, proceeding with boot."
    starling.get("digest_scheduler")
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use mod_passenger (phusion)? I moved from mongrel to phusion and it worked perfect (with a timeamount of < 5 minutes)!

Comment: I am afraid that is impossible.

Comment: Maybe you want to use another (maybe better) plugin?

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/queueing.html

Comment: I ended up using a dummy file and exclusive file lock to settle this.

Comment: phusion will have the same issues with rufus-scheduler as multiple mongrels.  See [the documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_smart_spawning_gotcha_2_the_need_to_revive_threads) on how to revive threads.